# How to append or insert an HTML element in existing DOM in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to append or insert an HTML element in existing DOM(any element in DOM) on a click of a button? Had it appended, how to populate yet be written content after click of button in that appended element? 
I know in Jquery it's a piece of cake but I want React to help me out this time.

Here is the code :  i want to populate add `<p></p>` in 'editor' div and populate content what i will write after clicking button.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  parargraph(e){
    const parargraph = '<p></p>';
    alert(parargraph);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className={"editorHolder " + (this.props.active ? 'show' : '' )  } onClick={this.hideEditor}>
      <div className="editBar">
      <ul>
        <li><button onClick={this.parargraph}>Parargraph</button></li>
        <li><button>H1</button><button>H2</button><button>H3</button><button>H4</button><button>H5</button><button>H6</button></li>
        <li><button>Image</button></li>
        <li><button>Link</button></li>
        <li><button>List</button></li>
        <li><button>Audio</button></li>
        <li><button>Video</button></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="editor">
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far and where you're stuck at

Comment: sure. I thought answer would be a small piece of code, and adding my code might make this question confusing.

Answer (score 0):

React offers a way to directly manipulate the innerHTML of a div.

Check out [dangerouslySetHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

For your code, try this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      content: ''
    }
    this.paragraph = this.paragraph.bind(this)
  }

  paragraph(e){
    const paragraph = '<p></p>'
    let content = this.state.content
    content += paragraph
    this.setState({content})
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className={"editorHolder " + (this.props.active ? 'show' : '' )  } onClick={this.hideEditor}>
      <div className="editBar">
      <ul>
        <li><button onClick={this.paragraph}>Paragraph</button></li>
        <li><button>H1</button><button>H2</button><button>H3</button><button>H4</button><button>H5</button><button>H6</button></li>
        <li><button>Image</button></li>
        <li><button>Link</button></li>
        <li><button>List</button></li>
        <li><button>Audio</button></li>
        <li><button>Video</button></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="editor" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.content}}>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Explanation: You would want to keep the content of the editor in the state, ready to change and append more content upon clicking of any of the buttons. The editor div will receive the state and updates its value upon state change.

PS: It's good practice to bind your component methods in the constructor, I've done it for you in the sample code.
You also misspelled 'paragraph'.

Comment: Thnaks for help. With this i am able to append an element to DOM but populating written data inside that appended element is out of hand stil.